# Word for kicking the ball far away from opponent's goal in Association Football

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

When a player is trying to score in Association Football (Soccer in American English) and kicks the ball with too much power and with misdirection, so that it completely misses the goal (typically by going too high), is there an idiomatic word in British English to express that?

Comment: I've heard *'punt'*, though I'm not sure it's what you're looking for.

Comment: That's only in rugby or American football, no?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know about sports.

Comment: Sure, something like this, yeah

Comment: 'Clearance' is kicking the ball away from the goalmouth to avoid a goal being scored. Kicking the ball away from the goalmouth in an attempt to score would be 'ignorance'.

Comment: I know that the urge to find mistakes makes one feel important, but you either have no idea what we are talking about, or didn’t even bother reading my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ***[sky the ball](https://languagecaster.com/football-language-sky-the-ball/)***:

> when the player has hit the ball too hard and it has gone over the bar - not just over the bar but a long way over  the bar.

(languagecaster.com)

Comment: Sweeeet! That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @SAdam That's a really good answer but only applies to shots that are too high. You seemed also to be interested in shots that went wide but not high, "skying' the ball would not apply to that.

Comment: @BoldBen - That’s true. Do you happen to have a more general word that applies to all situations?

Comment: With all due respect, I got there first.

Comment: It is not always necessary to provide a source, and it is especially difficult for the contemporary spoken word. My own impression is that “sky” and “skyer” are both somewhat old-fashioned — rather “Roy of the Rovers”.

Comment: @SAdam I don't have a more general term apart from 'terrible shot' which applies even more generally. I don't think there is a term for shots that go badly wide in the way that skying the ball goes badly high.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are adjectives like “skyer” and simple phrases like “well wide” or “well over the bar”, a British football description more on the lines of what is requested is:

> That one landed in row Z

The seating rows are numbered from A, at the bottom, so row Z is much too high.

or, if the ball wasn’t so high, a commentator would often say:

> The ball was *always rising*

As regards the supplementary question/comment for an expression that is *not specific to being too high or too wide*:

> The shot was well *off target*

is used, although not particularly idiomatic. A more colourful expression, would be:

> That one *scared the pigeons*

although at Brighton, Blackpool or Bournmouth, it would be transformed to something like:

> That one *scattered the seagulls*